# Generalised Gamma distribution R

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, extrapolation

I've been stuck on this for a while, and it is probably something so simple but hey I'm bogged down.

I've been using the `flexsurv` package, and I've got the following

```
coefficients: 
MU: 1.8664
SIGMA: 0.1701
Q: -47.8063
```

I'm trying to extrapolate these coefficients, and get the values for 1:1000

Can anyone please help...much appreciated

Comment: You mean generate 1000 generalized gamma random numbers with those parameters?

Comment: I am trying to find the curve with those coefficents, so y-axis would be 0:1 and x would be 1:1000 (i apologize if my explanations are too simple :$)

Comment: Then you just need a for loop over the PDF

Answer (score 1):

If your question is to generate random numbers using those parameters,  call:

`rgengamma(n = 1000, mu = 0, sigma = 1, Q = -1)`

see:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/flexsurv.pdf